# TSQL - Multiple aliases for CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that selects columns from a table where the condition is met, the problem is this logic is repeated several times (once for each column required) and wondered if there was a better way of doing it.

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN (date1 IS NULL) THEN [date2]       
    WHEN (date1 IS NOT NULL OR ( date1 IS NOT NULL AND date2 IS NOT NULL )) THEN [date1]
    ELSE ''
  END AS selectedDate

//Repeat above statement for [day], [hour], [minute]
```

I want to know if its possible to aggregate a number of these case statements under the same statement with separate aliases as they all rely on the same conditions instead of rewriting the same statement multiple times for each column, for example I tried the following:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN (date1 IS NULL) THEN [date2] as "selectedDate", [day2] as "day", [hour2] as "hour", [minute2] as "minute"  
    WHEN (date1 IS NOT NULL OR ( date1 IS NOT NULL AND date2 IS NOT NULL )) THEN [date1] as "selectedDate", [day1] as "day", [hour1] as "hour", [minute1] as "minute"   
    ELSE ''
```

Comment: You could write a function that holds the CASE logic and just provide your dates to it, if it should get out of hand.

Comment: @Jens i was thinking that, but id have to pass the column as a parameter rather than the value wouldnt I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the way you are describing...

An alternative would be to use [**`isnull()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) or [**`coalesce()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
select 
    SelectedDate = coalesce(date1,date2)
  , [Day]        = coalesce(day1,day2)
  , [Hour]       = coalesce(hour1,hour2)
  , [Minute]     = coalesce(minute1,minute2)
from t
```

Answer (score 2):

No. Each column needs its own select statement.

For your particular application of this CASE statement, you could be using [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) instead.

```
SELECT COALESCE(date1, date2) AS selectedDate FROM SomeTable
```